# How to write "params" in JSON-RPC 2.0 in C#?

Tags: c#, json, json-rpc

I want to use JSON-RPC to control an application called aria2. I can control it when it doesn't need params. But I tried many ways, I never successful in controlling it with params.

Some of the code I've tried is like this:

```
if (secret != null && secret != "")
    json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new JObject { ["jsonrpc"] = "2.0", ["id"] = "m", ["method"] = "aria2.addUri", ["params"] = { "token:" + secret, "[http://csharp.org/file.zip]" } });
else
    json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new JObject { ["jsonrpc"] = "2.0", ["id"] = "m", ["method"] = "aria2.addUri", ["params"] = @"[http://csharp.org/file.zip]" });
```

I also tried:

```
if (secret != null && secret != "")
    string json = "{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\",\"method\": \"aria2.addUri\",\"params\": {\"token:\"" + secret + "\",\"http://csharp.org/file.zip\"},\"id\": \"m\"}";
else
    string json = "{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\",\"method\": \"aria2.addUri\",\"params\": {\"http://csharp.org/file.zip\"},\"id\": \"m\"}";
```

And I have tried many combinations and permutations with `[{'"` but nothing works.

> Here is the RPC guide about aria2 for Python:
>   https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#rpc-authorization-secret-token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution may some beginners want to know.

> First, know what you want to output, in this case is:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"m","method":"aria2.addUri","params":["token:secret",["http://csharp.org/file.zip"]]}
```

Result is here: http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=4ee8fb1e0314e124bd3ab7d4b2ed19f1

---

And then, the little tip, `[]` is outside from the params's value, so they're arrays, not string. It can't use `["params"] = {}`, it also won't cover string to array, for example, following wrong code:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new JObject { ["params"] = "[\"token:secret\", [\"http://csharp.org/file.zip\"]]" });
```

only get:

```
{"params":"[\"token:secret\", [\"http://csharp.org/file.zip\"]]"}
```

---

> The most important is **the format of token**, it's not a
>   `JProperty()` in `JObject()`, it's just a string in params's
>   `JArray()`. And uri is also in params's `JArray()`'s `JArray()`. So
>   the right version is:

```
JArray param = new JArray { "token:secret", new JArray { "http://csharp.org/file.zip" } };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new JObject { ["jsonrpc"] = "2.0", ["id"] = "m", ["method"] = "aria2.addUri", ["params"] = param });
```

- `JArray()` is `[]`, `JObject()` is `{}`; `JArray()` ≠ `JObject()`.

---

> If we don't need `JsonConvert()`, the right version is easy:

```
string json = "{ \"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"id\": \"m\", \"method\": \"aria2.addUri\", \"params\": [\"token:secret\", [\"http://csharp.org/file.zip\"]] }";
```

- We can't change `"` to `'` in this case.